How to synchronize ES6 Map used for React Form Values in multiple async fetches
(I know that setters are asynchronous, I need a solution for how to mutate a unified Map and guarantee all values in the Map are thread-safe.)
In our React app, instead of using individual state variables, we have a unified valueMap ES6 Map that gathers all form values. It has a mutator called handleValueMapChange(key,value). The inputs are hooked up to that valueMap as e.g. value={props.valueMap.get('someField')}.
// Definition
const [valueMap, setValueMap] = useState<Map<string, any>>(new Map());

// Mutator
const handleValueMapChange = (id: string, value: any) => {
    setValueMap(new Map<string, any>(valueMap.set(id, value)));
}

On certain input, there is a point where multiple async fetches are called in quick succession, and they will call handleValueMapChange to manually set some values into the form.
// Example of multiple async fetches that are called in quick succession to manually set into valueMap
const fetchXX = async () => {
   const response = await get<any>('app/fetchXX');
   if (response) {
       props.handleValueMapChange('fieldXX', response); 
    } 
};

What I'm finding is that some intermediate valueMap entries get lost. The goal is to have all of these valueMap fields correctly set eventually regardless of  where they get set from. Suppose fetch1 sets handleValueMapChange('field1','abc') and fetch2 sets handleValueMapChange('field2','def'), where they're both initially ''. At the end field1 is blank ('') in valueMap and the intermediate setting of that value from fetch1 got lost.
So the ES6 Map isn't synchronized. We chose the ES6 Map form approach to avoid having lots of individual variables, and also to make it easier to submit the form to the server as one variable instead of many. Are there any solutions to this?

https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state

I know that setters are asynchronous. I'm asking what the solution would be for this unified Map approach (as opposed to keeping separate variables where asynchronous setting wouldn't be a problem). Now that I have a unified map approach, what's the solution to this?

The solution is using the form documented above. You were already told how to do it.

Yes that worked. I missed that earlier response because it wasn't directly related to the question at the time.

This is the solution,
setValueMap(prevValueMap => {
    const newValueMap = new Map(prevValueMap);
    newValueMap.set(id, value);
    return newValueMap;
});

The updater function => was used per this documentation
